# How to wrap XML in CDDATA in Embperl?

Tags: xml, perl

I have following XML code (`$xml`) that needs to be displayed in a page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Contact name="test" course="maths">
</Contact>
```

In the displaying page, I am getting the following error:

```
XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
```

instead of displaying the XML.

I tried to remove the line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

and it displays correctly.

My issue is that I can't always do the above step as in future there will be another format.

As a permanent solution I want to wrap this xml to CDDATA and tried in perl like:

```
$modified_xml = '<![CDATA['.$xml.']]>;
```

and it displays the error like:

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
<![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Contact name="test" course="maths"></Contact>]]>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Is a special case - it's the XML declaration. It *must* be on it's own line, and (if present) it must be the first line. It's *not* part of your XML.

So no, you can't insert it into a `CDATA` like that. It's not going to work.

Your error there - suggests it's "not at the start of entity" which usually means you've stray blank lines.

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $xml = '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Contact name="test" course="maths">
</Contact>';

XML::Twig -> parse ( $xml );
```

Errors with:

```
XML or text declaration not at start of entity at line 2, column 0, byte 1
```

But:

```
my $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Contact name="test" course="maths">
</Contact>';

XML::Twig -> parse ( $xml );
```

Doesn't.

Can I suggest as your 'fix' - first get valid XML. But second:

```
$xml =~ s/\A\s*//gms;
```